# Ancillary statistic not containing information about sample distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

From [a note](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~doksum/STAT709/n709-21.pdf) by Jun Shao

> If $V(X)$ is a nontrivial ancillary statistic, then $σ(V(X)) ⊂ σ(X)$ is a nontrivial σ-field that **does not contain any information about** $P$.

I was wondering in what sense "the σ-field of statistic $V(X)$ does not contain any information about the distribution $P$ of $X$" means?

1. I learned that σ-field itself represents information, but not sure
   about what it means by σ-field of $V(X)$ not containing information
   about distribution of $X$.
2. Does "information" here mean the fisher information?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 2):

It means that the probability distribution of V does not involve the parameter, or, if you prefer, that the Fisher information is null.